# How to setup an optional parameter with an IN operator inside the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that has two optional parameters. Both of these parameters are comma delimited strings that I would like to use within the IN operator.

Let's say that I have some SQL like this:

```
@ManagersCommaDelimited VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@EmployeesCommaDelimited VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SELECT t1.*, t2.Field1
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1id
WHERE (@ManagersCommaDelimited IS NOT NULL AND t1.ManagerId IN (@ManagersCommaDelimited))
AND (@EmployeesCommaDelimited IS NOT NULL AND t1.EmployeeId IN (@EmployeesCommaDelimited))
```

If either of these parameters are NULL or Whitespace I would like to ignore the part with the IN operator.

So if ManagersCommaDelimited is NULL then I want to return records with all records and if ManagersCommaDelmited is not NULL then I want to return records with only the managers within the comma delimited string parameter.

How can I accomplish this in MS SQL?

Comment: Delimited string is real problem here. If you need that many options you should consider using table valued parameters instead. With delimited lists you either need dynamic sql or a string splitter. Both of those approach have their own set of issues. Best to just avoid it and go with the table valued parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use IN if you are comparing to a subset of data. 
The OP solution is to check the existence of a string therefore use CharIndex

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql

```
WHERE (ISNULL(@ManagersCommaDelimited, '') <> ''
AND CHARINDEX(@ManagersCommaDelimited, CAST(t1.ManagerId AS varchar(max)) > 0))  --- if there is a match of text then will return the position
```